# Load ONNX CNTK C++ raises exception

Tags: cntk

I have one file that I created in matlab.  I used it very well in
python load:

```
import cntk as C
z = C.Function.load("Net.onnx", format=C.ModelFormat.ONNX)
```

in c++ I have exception  `Selected CPU as the process wide default device.`

About to throw exception:

> 'Gemm: Invalid shape, input A and B are expected to be rank=2
>   matrices'

I used the nuget imported :  `CNTK.CPUOnly CNTK.Deps.MKL CNTK.Deps.OpenCV.Zip`

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "CNTKLibrary.h"

 void main(){

     std::wstring modelFile(L"Net.onnx");

     //line crash
     CNTK::FunctionPtr modelFunc = CNTK::Function::Load(modelFile, CNTK::DeviceDescriptor::CPUDevice(), CNTK::ModelFormat::ONNX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finaly i made other solution i save in python to model cntk than loaded it from c++
in cntk format (where original model was exported from matlab to onnx long way)

python code

```
import cntk as C
z = C.Function.load("Net.onnx", format=C.ModelFormat.ONNX)
z.save(os.path.join("folder", "net" + ".dnn"))
```

c++ loading

```
#include "CNTKLibrary.h"
std::wstring modelFile(L"net.dnn");

CNTK::FunctionPtr modelFunc = CNTK::Function::Load(modelFile, CNTK::DeviceDescriptor::CPUDevice());
```